# nomenclature page formatting

Tags: spacing, sectioning, page-breaking, nomenclature

I have a list of symbols generated throught the `nomencl` package. It works fine. The only problem I have is:

1. How can I redefine the margins for the page? by default it is using the margins for chapter. I want to set smaller margin on top for this page.
2. Is it possible to generate nomenclature without a page break, like it starts where the previous text ends?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's always the best to ask more than one question if you have different topics. For your first question see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry and the second question can be done too.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The first question rather seems like a request to reduce the spacing before the nomenclature heading.

Comment: @lockstep: Really? The op wants to change the margins.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel "smaller margin *on top*" (emphasis added)

Comment: @lockstep: "@"USER26016: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You probably want to redefine `\thenomenclature`. In order to sugest the best way for this we would need to see an MWE that shows how you're using `nomencl`.

Answer (score 2):

In a document class with chapters, `nomencl` will set the nomenclature as an unnumbered chapter, otherwise as a section. To make the nomenclature a section even in a chaptered document like `book`, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}%
  {\chapter*{\nomname}}%
  {\section*{\nomname}}%
  {}{\message{^^Jthenomenclature patching failed (1)^^J}}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}%
  {\if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi}%
  {\if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi}%
  {}{\message{^^Jthenomenclature patching failed (2)^^J}}
\makeatother
```

Note however, that then the nomenclature, as a section, will belong to the chapter that started before, and this will show, e.g., in the Table of Contents. This might not really be what you want.

Comment: “This might not really be what you want.” That's why I didn't answer but decided to wait for an MWE...

Comment: @cgnieder Well, I think after all it is what the OP asked for, but I doubt that he *should* want that ;-)

Comment: [I guessed that, too](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98442/nomenclature-page-formatting/98480#comment212301_98442) but since so many people use `nomencl` by copying some definition they found somewhere on the internet I rather decided to wait... If you answer and it's not what the OP wants you may have wasted your time... OTOH maybe it _is_ what he/she wants

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Works like a charm. I added my own heading and used \addcontentsline to include it in toc. Thanks a million.